# get object value on IE 11 from data layer

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, internet-explorer, google-datalayer

I have a few variables/object in js that are beeing fecth from data layer, the issues i'm facing is that IE11 doesn't work good with objects,

```
 <script>
 var pagenumber= dataLayer[0].pageName;
 /// this output 397 which use to a few front end functions, works good on all browsers except IE


     var x = {Name: 'John', Age: 30, City: 'Bangalore'};

   Object.prototype.values = function(obj) {
                            var res = [];
for (var i in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        res.push(obj[i]);
    }
   }
     return res;
   };


 console.dir(Object.values(x));
// i do see objects and value on EI11 with this method
 </script>
```

how can i get pagenumber value only and store his value in a variable

[image]

added the way data layer is pushing data. my main issue here is IE 11 and older versions until IE 8 is ok, im new to IE issues with js arrays/objects

Comment: You probably need to convert the JSON into an object. `var dataObj = JSON.parse(dataLayer);`

Comment: how will i struture that if all i want is the value of pagenumber which in this case is  "397"

Comment: `var dataObj = JSON.parse(dataLayer);` `var pageNumber = dataObj[0].pageName;`

Comment: i got this Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: That would tend to suggest that you are not receiving well formed JSON (or possibly no JSON at all). Place a debugger at that point and inspect the `dataLayer` value, or look at the request/response in your dev tools network tab.

Comment: i tried all u said but can't figure out what to do,, what do you need to continue assisting me

Comment: What does the JSON look like? `console.log(dataLayer) ;`

Comment: [object Array][Object {...}]   0[object Object] {...}  [functions] __proto__[object Object] {...}  __proto__null

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.stringify((dataLayer));` What does that output to the console?

Comment: [{"UserLogged":"no","pageName":"1182","pageLanguage":"es","ServerDate":"17/5/2018 21:58:52"},       only in chrome on IE11 i have nothing

Comment: So, the issue seems to be retrieving the results of the API call in IE, rather than accessing an object value in IE. Without seeing the code that makes (and handles) the API call, I would have no idea. I suggest deleting this post and starting another with that code in it, and asking why the data is not returned in IE.